# How to make cmdline with bazel genrule concatenate multiple srcs with cmdline options?

Tags: bazel, bazel-genrule

I have a cmdline tool which can accept multiple inputs with different cmd options.

```bash
mytool --include=some_include1 --include=some_include2 --inlcude=... source1 source2 ...
```

So I have to write a `genrule` with

```py
filegroup(
  name = "include_group",
  srcs = ["some_include1", "some_include2"],
)

filegroup(
  name = "source_group",
  srcs = ["source1", "source2"],
)

genrule(
  name = "myrule",
  srcs = [":include_group"] + [":source_group"],
  outs = ["out.cpp"],
  tools = ["mytool"],
  cmd = "$(location :mytool) --include=$(locations :path_group) $(locations :source_group)"
)
```

The cmd line tunout to be:

```bash
mytool --include=some_include1 some_include2 source1 source2
```

Notice that the option label of `some_include2` is missing.

So my question is: how to add the option label to each label in `:include_group`.

Answer (score 0):

The `genrule`'s `cmd` attribute is shell, which can be used for such expansion:

```
genrule(
  name = "myrule",
  srcs = [":include_group"] + [":source_group"],
  outs = ["out.cpp"],
  tools = ["mytool"],
  cmd = """
includes=($(locations :include_group))
$(location :mytool) $${includes[@]/#/--include=} $(locations :source_group)
"""
)
```

There are other, possibly more portable, ways such as writing a wrapper script for `mytool` that reads the includes from a file. A custom Bazel rule could also easily generate such a command line.